# Change Partiton Order

Tags: partitioning, windows-10, multi-boot

How can I change the partition order! I dual booted Windows 10 and 7 and I want to extend the partition size. The Windows 10 partition is at the end. How can I switch the order?

Comment: Partitions represent the physical layout on disk.  If you want to make significant changes, you will need to Google a third party tool that can shift the data around.

Comment: ok where can I find one?

Comment: By Googling for a third party tool like @Paul said...